# Need to give a user "superadmin" status through database

Tags: 6

There doesn't appear to be a superuser on the users table. 
Whenever I try to access permissions directly I get "Access denied", even though my user is listed as and Admin.

How can I promote another user to superuser status through the database?

Comment: For your information, uid 0 is the guest. Uid 1 is the "super admin" that's created at installation of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I promote another user to superuser status through the
>   database?

There's only one "superuser" or root user in Drupal. That user has uid 1

Perhaps you need to update that user's password.

In D6, using just SQL, you can go

```
UPDATE users SET pass = MD5('password') WHERE uid = 1;
```

and then login with that username and password.

Note, make sure that's ok with the current uid 1 user, if it's not you.

Answer (score 0):

Super user is always uid 1, as mentioned in the other answer.

If you hav deleted the super user you can add a new one by either:

Create a new user, then in the database update their uid to 1.

OR

You could also run this database query to add the user manually:

```
INSERT INTO users (uid, name, pass, mail, theme, signature, status, language, picture, init, timezone_name)
values (1, 'your username', MD5('password'), 'your.email@example.com', '', '', 1, '', '', 'your.email@example.com', '');
```

When manually creating a user like that you should then go into their user account page and set check all the settings are what they should be.

Also, if someone has accidentally deleted the user 1 user that is bad.
If you have other administrators that have the administer users permission, you should use the [userprotect](http://drupal.org/project/userprotect) module and configure it so that those users cannot mess with user 0 or user 1.

Comment: If the user 1 record doesn't exist, you can also just update another existing user record to uid 1. i.e: `UPDATE users SET uid = 1 WHERE uid = 2;`

Comment: Agreed, that was the first part of my answer (minus the actual sql, which isn't so necessary with phpmyadmin).